# Find all increasing sequences of $k$ numbers, created from $n$ different numbers, $k\le n$.

Tags: combinatorics

Given a set of $n$ different numbers, create increasing sequences of $k$ numbers, selected from the $n$ numbers. Obviously, $k\le n$.
It looks to me like the answer is the binomial coefficient, and this is another interpretation of it. The binomial coefficient is $n/k$ number of ways to choose $k$ elements, irrespective of their order, from a set of $n$ elements. The order is not important, and there is only one way to arrange them in an ascending order, because they're all different.

Answer (score 1):

You are right, the answer is $\binom{n}{k}$, since there is only one way to sort the $k$ numbers.